# How to prove $AP$ is constant in this plane geometry problem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

As is shown in the picture, $ ∠ACB=∠EDB=90^{o},AC=2,BC=4,AE=3,ED=DB,∠PCD=45^{o}$, how to prove that $AP=1$?

[image]

By adding additional conditions (like $AE$ is parallel to $CB$) I can verify that $AP=1$. I try to find similar triangles in the graph, but I haven't found.

Comment: I don't see a synthetic approach right off, but if I were to coordinatize, I'd start by noticing that $A$, $B$, $C$ are fixed. Then I'd choose $E$ on the circle of radius $3$ about $A$, which then determines $D$, and in turn $P$ (assuming $A$, $P$, $E$ collinear).

Comment: FYI: My quick-and-dirty analysis (corroborated by a GeoGebra sketch) that, in general, (barring degeneracies or alternative configurations) 
$$\frac{|PA|}{|PE|}= \frac{|AC|}{|BC|}$$

Comment: I guess you can establish a rectangular system(maybe ugly)

Comment: @ItozDarbien Right, so I wonder whether there is a geometric method.

Comment: @Blue Complex numbers led to a reasonable solution, helped in part by $45^\circ$ rotation is multiplying by $ (1+i)/2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the angle bisector of $ACB$ (which coincidentally gives us $45^\circ$) intersect $AB$ at $F$.
Let $ P^*$ on $AE$ such that $P^* F \parallel EB$.
Let $AC = a$, $CB = b$.

[image]

Show the following
(If you get stuck, explain what you've tried and what you're unable to push through)

1. $ \frac{CF}{CB} = \frac{ \sqrt{2} a}{a+b}$
2. $ \frac{P^*F}{DB}  = \frac{ \sqrt{2} a}{a+b}$
3. $ \angle P^*FC = \angle DBC$  (angles in red)
4. $ CFP^*$ and $CBD$ are similar triangles.
5. $\angle P^*CF = \angle DCB$   (angles in blue)
6. $\angle P^*CD = 45^\circ$
7. $P = P^*$
8. $\frac{AP}{PE}  = \frac{AF}{FB} = \frac{AC}{CB}$

Notes:

- $CP$ (and then $CD$) were the hardest to get a handle on. So we didn't use them directly, but instead got to it from the similar triangles.
- Constructing $F$ was motivated by "knowing" what the answer is, and relating those ratios. This solution was quite natural via a working backwards process.